# Substring only if string length > 2

Tags: sql, substring

I was wondering if it was possible to only substring if the string length is > 2?

Here is my sample statement:

`Select SUBSTRING(ABRESC, 1, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(ABRESC, 3, 5) AS ABRESC From TABLE`

However, some fields are only 2 chars long so i was wondering if its possible to only substring when its longer than 2 chars?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

```
Select ABRESC =
    CASE WHEN LEN(ABRESC) > 2 
       THEN SUBSTRING(ABRESC, 1, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(ABRESC, 3, 5)
       ELSE  ABRESC END  
From TABLE
```

Comment: As a note, the specific functions used for strings vary between databases.