# How to check string length and then select substring in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In a view, i have a column **comments** which may contain large string.
I just want to select first 60 characters and append the '**...**' at the end of the selected string.

For selecting first 60 characters i have used following query:

```
select LEFT(comments, 60) as comments from myview
```

Now i want its processing as below:

1. Check it contains more then 60 characters or not.
2. If contains then select only first 6o characters and append three dots at the end.
3. If it doesn't contain more then 60 characters then select whole string without appending three dots at the end.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Substring only if string length > 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899661/substring-only-if-string-length-2)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To conditionally check the length of the string, use `CASE`.

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN LEN(comments) <= 60 
             THEN comments
             ELSE LEFT(comments, 60) + '...'
        END  As Comments
FROM    myView
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/443e6/1)

Comment: Keep in mind that in first case max len of output string is 60 and in the second is 63!