# How to log or notify when a column is truncated using a LEFT()

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

As part of our OLAP modeling workflow, we are often truncating fields as upstream data sources have no restrictions or defined data types. A field which should be a 10 character string can sometimes be 50 or 100 characters long if it is a free form user input. I've been told this can cause problems with downstream processes which involve uploads to external sources.

I've been asked to find a way to identify instances in which one ore more of these fields is truncated.

How we handle these fields now is something like this:

```
SELECT
    LEFT(FreeResponseField, 10) AS Comment
INTO
    dbo.ModeledTable
FROM
    dbo.SourceTable
```

Essentially if the field is greater than 10 characters, who cares, we only take the first 10.

If `dbo.SourceTable.FreeResponseField` has a length greater than 10, now we want to know somehow (be it a warning/error message or insertion into a log table). We have a lot of tables with a lot of fields, so the above example is a simplification. Identifying just the field in which this occurs and/or the tuple in the table would be helpful to see where these issues are occurring.

Is something like this possible? You can't just compare data types of the source table with the target table as the source table sets everything to essentially `VARCHAR(MAX)`. The naive approach is to check the length every single value of every tuple against the defined length of the target table.

Comment: `we are often truncating fields as upstream data sources have no restrictions or defined data types`, this sounds like a bad design, really, specially if you know what data type the destination table is. I think in this case, checking the length would be the way to go

Comment: Would it be sufficient to add a bit/int field to the table and then make a CASE statement to flag the rows that have been truncated? @Lamak sometimes upstream data problems are unavoidable (data comes from external source and needs to be normalized or cleaned etc.)

Comment: @JacobH I think my biggest issue is I don't know if there's a clean way to identify when a LEFT() actually reduces the length of a field. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15091989/3220769) helps a little, but I want to trigger an event or update when the length is > X

Comment: what event do you want to trigger?, what update?. And the clean way would be to check the length

Comment: Yes that was going to be my suggestion, CASE with LEN. You can use CASE in an update.

Comment: @Lamak an insertion into a log table, or as JacobH suggested an update to a bit field. I guess the 2nd one could be done with a CASE but that requires modifying the structure of every table to account for every field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original specifications weren't descriptive, but I've figured out a solution and thought I'd share in case anyone stumbles across this for some reason.

Imagine we have a `SourceTable` which are pulling in to our model. We have defined zip codes as being of length 5 and addresses of being length 25. Say we have the following two records:

```
CustomerID | ZipCode | Address
         1 |   90210 | 123 Fake Street
         2 |  902106 | 546 Fake Street
```

Based on our model definitions, there is an error with `ZipCode` for the record where `CustomerID` equals 2. We would like to identify both `ZipCode` as being the problem field and the record where `CustomerID` equals 2. The following query with a `CROSS APPLY` does that:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        CustomerID,
        ZipCodeFlag = IIF(LEN(ZipCode) > 5, 1, 0),
        AddressFlag = IIF(Len(Address) > 25, 1, 0),
        ZipCode,
        Address
    FROM
        SourceTable
)
SELECT
    CustomerID,
    TruncatedField,
    RawValue
FROM
    CTE
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES ('ZipCode', ZipCodeFlag, ZipCode),
           ('Address', AddressFlag, Address)
) CA(TruncatedField, TruncatedFlag, RawValue)
WHERE
    TruncatedFlag = 1
ORDER BY
    CustomerID
```

With the following output:

```
CustomerID | TruncatedField | RawValue
         2 |        ZipCode |   902106
```